# sql delete based on date

Tags: java, sqlite

I am a total noob to java and sqlite.  This should be simple, but I have tried and searched and can't get it to work.  I have a date field in SQL that I am formatting as a sql date (MM/dd/yy).  I want to delete based on a date passed.  For the moment, I am only trying to display rows based on a passed date.

My code to run the query is:

```
String query = "select * from Peter1Score where    DateSort='"+convertSQLDate("09/20/15")+"'";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

My converSQLDate() is:

```
public static java.sql.Date convertSQLDate (String sqlDateIn)
{
    java.sql.Date returnDate = null;

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    Date parsed;
    try 
    {
        parsed = formatter.parse(sqlDateIn);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
        returnDate = sqlDate;
    }
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnDate;
}
```

I am passing 09/20/15 just for test.  I have a record with that date, but it doesn't get selected.

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to use a `PreparedStatement` and pass in a date (not string) to the query through `setDate(1, myDate)`. You may also need to pass in a `Calendar` for explicitly defining a time zone if your JVM would happen to be on a different zone/locale than SQLite is.

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing.

Comment: You're not _binding_ any variables into the statement (using the `setXY()` methods). You're just concatenating a string value (result of `Date.toString()`) into the query literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not binding any variables into the statement (using the `setXY()` methods of `PreparedStatement`). Instead, you're concatenating a string value (result of `Date.toString()`) into the query literal.

Try this instead:

```
String query = "select * from Peter1Score where DateSort=?";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setDate(1, convertSQLDate("09/20/15"));
```

Comment: Fine & sufficient answer, though try-with-resources could have been shown as quite suitable for JDBC.

Comment: I'm on mobile so I had to keep the code to a minimum; could amend it with proper resource handling later today.

Comment: That worked perfect.  I knew it was going to be something simple and I also suspected it had something to do with string / date mismatch, but couldn't see the forest for the trees.  Thank you.